# sqlalchemy: cannot save model with Date column

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have created a model via declarative_base:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    datefrom = Column(Date)
    dateto = Column(Date)
    active = Column(Boolean, index=True, default=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

When I try to save module to postgres database:

```
dfrom = datetime.datetime.strptime(somestring, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
dto = datetime.datetime.strptime(someotherstring, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
record = Record(datefrom=dfrom, dateto=dto)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
```

I got following error:

```
(DataError) invalid input syntax for type date: \"\"\nLINE 1: ...'2013-11-26'::date, '2013-12-27'::date...\n ^\n 'INSERT INTO test (datefrom, dateto, active, created) VALUES (%(datefrom)s, %(dateto)s, %(active)s, %(created)s) RETURNING test.id' {'created': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 27, 20, 12, 55, 716185), 'dateto': datetime.date(2013, 12, 27), 'datefrom': datetime.date(2013, 11, 26), 'active': True}
```

The similar error is for sqlite backend:

```
SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input. (original cause: TypeError: SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input.) 'INSERT INTO test (datefrom, dateto, active, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' [{'dateto': datetime.date(2013, 12, 27), 'datefrom': datetime.date(2013, 11, 26)}]
```

So what am I doing wrong? Shouldn't datetime.date object work that way?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime` returns a `datetime` object. If you want just the date, use `datetime.date.strptime`.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I wrongly copied the code. Of course I use ...strptime(...).date(). date class does not have strptime AFAIK.

Comment: ...so, did Blender's comment help you solve the problem? Are you still experiencing the issue? If so, can you update the question with your new code/errors? If it's solved, can you put an answer on the question?

Comment: It did not. Code in question is updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOT AN ANSWER*, *just thoughts for further investigation***:

Cannot reproduce the problem on SQLite. The self-contained code below runs without problem and produces the output provided. What are you doing different? Can you schrink the problem you have to a similar example and see how is it different? *(Note: using SA v0.8.3)*

**CODE:**

```
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# object model
class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    datefrom = Column(Date)
    dateto = Column(Date)
    active = Column(Boolean, index=True, default=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

# create db schema
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

# TEST INSERT DATA
somestring, someotherstring = '3/1/2008', '1/3/1988'
dfrom = datetime.datetime.strptime(somestring, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
dto = datetime.datetime.strptime(someotherstring, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
record = Record(datefrom=dfrom, dateto=dto)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
session.expunge_all()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2013-11-28 09:17:14,608 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("test")
2013-11-28 09:17:14,608 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-11-28 09:17:14,609 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
CREATE TABLE test (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        datefrom DATE,
        dateto DATE,
        active BOOLEAN,
        created DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CHECK (active IN (0, 1))
)


2013-11-28 09:17:14,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-11-28 09:17:14,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2013-11-28 09:17:14,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_test_active ON test (active)
2013-11-28 09:17:14,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2013-11-28 09:17:14,612 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2013-11-28 09:17:14,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2013-11-28 09:17:14,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO test (datefrom, dateto, active, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
2013-11-28 09:17:14,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('2008-01-03', '1988-03-01', 1, '2013-11-28 08:17:14.619000')
2013-11-28 09:17:14,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: So I ran your test script and it works ok. Then started modifying your test model and discovered stupid typo, where I used Date type instead of Integer type in one two other columns. Sorry guys for wasting your time. I should do less copy/paste next time.